# Bootstrap 4 input-group-addon not working

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm currently using Bootstrap 4 for a project in a JavaScript course im following, and im doing the HTML, but i've run into an issue with the input-group-addon class on a span. It's not showing like [the icon is showing in the tutorial](https://prnt.sc/10d2a7i)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Loan Calculator</title>
</head>
 <body class="bg-dark">
 <div class="contr">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
      <div class="card card-body text-center mt-5">
        <h1 class="heading display-5 pb-3">Loan Calculator</h1>
        <form id="loan-form">
          <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount" placeholder="Loan Amount">
          </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span id="input-group-addon">%</span>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="interest" placeholder="Interest Rate">
          </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-
```

JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: please add your output to compare

Comment: https://prnt.sc/10d2m87 sorry :)

Comment: Try using `input-group-prepend` in place of `input-group-addon`

Comment: Nope, still the same output, might just have to restart the HTML part if i can't fix it, might be a bug within other parts of my code and the way i added bootstrap :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure and class names are a little bit off. You need a `span.input-group-text` nested inside a `div.input-group-prepend`

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
      </div>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount" placeholder="Loan Amount">
    </div>
  </div>
```

`.input-group-addon` does not appear in the [v4.0 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/) that was for v3.

Comment: @tylerlecho Then please accept this answer!